# Laravel query builder; get distinct rows with sums

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

Say we have a SQL table named BoxContents with each row consisting of
id, boxID, itemID, and quantity.

Only unique value is id. I need to input boxID and get a list/array of itemIDs and their TOTAL quantity;

Example:
in BoxContents table:

| id | boxID | itemID | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | banana | 5 |
| 2 | foo | monkey | 1 |
| 3 | bar | bomb | 2 |
| 4 | foo | banana | 5 |
| 5 | bar | fuse | 2 |
| 6 | bar | banana | 5 |
| 7 | foo | banana | 5 |

result when querying box foo:

```
['banana'=>15, 'monkey'=>1]
```

result when querying box bar:

```
['bomb'=>2, 'fuse'=>2, 'banana'=>5]
```

How would I go about making a query?

```
DB::table('BoxContents')
    ->where('boxID', 'foo')
    ->select('itemID', SUM('quantity'))
    ->distinct();
```

is what I got so far, but `SUM()` is obviously not accepted in `select()`

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via [`selectRaw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#selectraw)/[`DB::raw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions):

```
DB::table('BoxContents')
    ->where('boxID', 'foo')
    ->select('itemID', DB::raw("SUM('quantity')"))
    ->distinct();
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know DB::raw can be used like this, this will come in handy in the future! Also, thank you for the styling on my question :)